# SmtpException - Connection was forcibly closed by remote host. / The operation has timed out

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient

all. My intention in this project is to create a process-completion alert system by allowing other programs to make a call to my program, and send an SMS message to a cell phone with a message informing the recipient of the process completion (in my case, 3ds Max renderings).

Unfortunately, this section of code utterly fails. It executes without an issue up until "smtp.Send(msg);", at which point the SmtpException informs me that the remote host forcibly closed my "existing connection."

```
   MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
   msg.From = new MailAddress("zaccrites@att.net");
   msg.To.Add("zaccrites@att.net");
   msg.Subject = "Subject";
   msg.Body = "THIS IS A MESSAGE!";

   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.att.yahoo.com", 645);
   //smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
   //smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
   smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("zaccrites@att.net", "password");
   smtp.EnableSsl = true;

   Console.WriteLine("Send Start...");
   smtp.Send(msg);
   Console.WriteLine("Message Sent");
```

I feel like I should know what's going on here, but I just don't. I've searched for hours and hours over the internet, finding people with similar situations to mine, yet no one deigned to respond to their pleas for assistance. Perhaps my luck will be better here.

Thank you all.

Interestingly, the remote host is no longer forcibly closing my connection. The operation is simply timing out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not working, are you sure your firewall is not blocking you? Try to telnet into the SMTP server (dos prompt -> telnet smtp.att.yahoo.com 645. Also, try to add the mail server information in the app.config like this:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="testuser@domail.com">
            <network defaultCredentials="true" host="smtp.att.yahoo.com" port="645" userName="yourUser" password="yourPass"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons:

1. The machine it's running on is blocking the connection.  For example firewall / antivirus.
2. A device on the machine's local network is blocking the connection.  Firewall / router configuration.
3. The ISP's network (that the machine is on) is blocking the connection.
4. The SMTP server you're connecting to (Yahoo) just doesn't like your machine.

The last one is the most likely.  The best way to troubleshoot is to try sending to a different account on a different server.

Comment: Well I'm having the same issue even when I turn off my firewall, so I don't think its 1 or 2. Outlook doesn't seem to have a problem with the same settings, so I don't think it's number 4 either.

Comment: Great!  Since Outlook works, that should rule out 1, 2, and 3 (unless your firewall limits the number of connections per minute or only allows connections during a certain time of day or has a "whitelist" of programs).  The next step is to try with a different provider (Gmail, etc).  There is still a strong possibility that Yahoo doesn't "trust" your machine (option #4), and so it intentionally rejects the occasional connection to discourage spam (since a "real" mail client will retry later).